# Swift POST or GET request for user authentication iOS Swift

Tags: ios, swift, authentication

I was wondering if there are any advantages/disadvantages in using POST/GET method in Swift 2 to send password and username to the web server in order to authenticate the user. I am working on the iPhone application that fetches data from the web. The request passes the parameters to the URL and server sends data back. I modeled the current application with Enums defining a different endpoints for each request and it would be really easy for me to model Login the same way. However, I am not sure if that is the right direction.

Comment: Check http://stackoverflow.com/a/3353951/1457385

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So essentially `GET` is used to retrieve remote data, and `POST` is used to add/update remote data.

For security reasons, it does not make any difference. Just be sure that your connection is secured with an https certificate, and do not allow http connections.