# Is it possible to access POST data from a curl request? PHP

Tags: php, security, post, curl

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How secure is a HTTP POST?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1008668/how-secure-is-a-http-post)

I need to send sensitive information from Server A to Server B (to do some DB queries on it) using the POST method in cURL.

I need to know if its possible for someone to actually access the POST data during the request?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, a *man in the middle* or simply an entity in what is usually known as a *privileged network position* can read any data your server sends and receives. To protect your traffic from snooping, you should use an SSL protected connection. This even allows you to do a two-sided authentication if you use certificates for both sides, i.e. the sender can verify the receiver and the receiver can verify the sender.