# Security of passing GET parameters in URL through login page

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, security, get

**Background:** In my ASP.NET application, I occasionally need to pass the user through an intermediate page, which then must relink to the original requested page. I would like to maintain as many GET parameters as is feasible.

For example, if the user lands on:

- `store.aspx?storeId=34&myHours=12`

But I now realize the user needs to go to the intermediate page, so the user is redirected:

- `siteAd.aspx?returnTo=store.aspx&params=storeId%3D34%26myHours%3D12`

siteAd.aspx.vb will then have code to return the user to the original page (pseudocode):

```
Dim sReturnTo = Request.QueryString("returnTo")
' <insert code to protect against open-redirection attack on sReturnTo>
lnkContinue.HRef = sReturnTo & "?" & Request.QueryString("params")
```

**Question**: Are there any security concerns with the above scenario, as long as I make sure to protected against an [open-redirection vulnerability](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Open_redirect) in the `returnTo` parameter?

Comment: why not just URL encode the whole returnTo URL instead of splitting the query string from the path? e.g `returnTo=store.aspx%3fstoreId%3D34%26myHours%3D12`

Comment: Make sure "javascript: " can't be written or, closing the tag  """>bla bla .. some js... ". If you make sure the data is properly url encoded you shouldn't see a problem.

Comment: @SamGreenhalgh seems like this easiest way to avoid an open-redirection attack. I can't see how this would help in terms of security either.

Comment: @patstuart, sorry I wasn't offering an answer just wondering why you'd done that. I don't see any other attack vector based on you suggestion, although without knowing what the rest of your code does to validate and build up the URL is difficult to be sure.

Comment: Why are you not using SSL?

Comment: @Chr where does the OP say that they aren't using SSL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution I came up with was to URLEncode the *entire* string (per @SamGreenhalgh), then to use the built-in .NET function [IsWellFormedUriString](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uri.iswellformeduristring.aspx) as such:

```
Private Shared Function isLocalUrl(ByVal sUrl As String) As Boolean
    If String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(sUrl) Then
        Return False
    End If

    sUrl = sUrl.Trim
    Return Uri.IsWellFormedUriString(sUrl, UriKind.Relative)
End Function
```

Comment: @Chris I think it is. `IsWellFormedUriString` allows a very limited set of characters. Any HTML characters like `<>&'"` are disallowed, so I do not have to worry about someone clicking a bad link and suddenly running an injection, or being sent to the wrong site.

Answer (score 0):

As [@Sam Greenhalgh](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27256258/security-of-passing-get-parameters-in-url-through-login-page#comment42986483_27256258) said why not pass the whole path and query string as one parameter rather than splitting. If it is correctly URL encoded, then this will be OK.

As well as the Open Redirection Vulnerability, you should secure your code against XSS by checking that `lnkContinue.HRef` can only be set to a HTTP or HTTPS URL. This will prevent someone creating a link to your site where `returnTo` contains JavaScript. e.g. `javascript:alert('xss')`

The [Uri](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uri%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) obect can be used to validate that `returnTo` isn't an open redirect or XSS attack. The protocol can be checked to make sure it is HTTP or HTTPS and the Url itself can be checked to see whether it is a relative URL or if it is an absolute URL pointing to your domain. It is better to use the Url object that executing manual string comparison methods. Many open redirect checks can be fooled by the attacker setting up domains such as `www.example.com.evil.com` to fool the domain check for `www.example.com` or by including `www.example.com` elsewhere in the URL (e.g. `http://www.evil.com/www.example.com/Page.aspx`).

Answer (score -1):

URL Encoding is not a security measure and it is trivial to defeat. The best way to protect against Man-in-the-Middle attacks is to use HTTPS with a reputable SSL certificate and switch from GET to POST. Anything else is tiptoeing around the issue (i.e security)

Also see https://stackoverflow.com/a/1008550/374075

Comment: It would be great if you could provide a comment about down voting so other people can benefit as well. Or do you go about down voting people in random? Be an adult and behave like one!

Comment: Sorry, thought I'd commented although I realise now I asked you about your comment to the question but you didn't reply. The threat here isn't related to whether the data in the URL is encrypted or not. The vulnerability the OP was concerned about [Open Redirect](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Open_redirect), and the vulnerability I identified in my answer ([XSS](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Cross-site_Scripting_%28XSS%29)) would not be mitigated by the use of SSL. Even if the URL was HTTPS they would still be vulnerabilities.

Comment: Yes, TLS is always a good move and can protect against MITMs, I agree with you there. Unfortunately this would not address @pat's concerns here.

Comment: Point taken. Thanks for your reply, much appreciated. I learned something today :)